# Why do dask divisions need to be unique?

Tags: dask

I want to set the index for a `dask` dataframe (`from_delayed`) using already known divisions. However, dask complains that the divisions are required to be unique. This constraint causes trouble for me since the partitions would turn out to be of about 5GB in size which is a bit too much for my taste.

Is there a way to work around this constraint or loosen it for certain operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should view the divisions as an optimisation, which allows dask to know which data is expected in which partition for some operations (groupby, fetch particular index row, etc.).

If your data is not organised in a way that the divisions on the index are unique, you have a simple option: do not provide divisions at all. Then you will lose out on those certain optimisations, which are not appropriate to your case. Alternatively, you could decide to reorganise your data, either within data or before passing it to dask.